# Unable to access uploaded .csv file for chatbot process by using OpenAI API key in next.js project

Tags: next.js, openai-api

I am having problems accessing an uploaded `.csv` file for chatbot process using the OpenAI API in my [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project.

The goal is to provide the API:

- the user query
- a `.csv` file

and have the AI provide responses based on those two things.

The API is working fine, but I'm unable to retrieve responses from the chatbot based on query queries and the data contained in the `.csv` file.

Note:Chatbot process if we uploaded any csv file.It should be implement with chatbot responses.

Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?